# Upcasting a generic type constructor to its upper bound

Tags: scala

Why doesn't the following compile?

```scala
def test[T, C[_] <: Iterable[_]](x: C[T]) = {
  val z: Iterable[T] = x
}
```

(scala 2.12.8)

I'm getting the following error:

```
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : C[T]
[error]  required: Iterable[T]
[error]     val z: Iterable[T] = x
[error]                          ^
[info] C[T] <: Iterable[T]?
[info]   Iterable[_$1] = Iterable[_$1]?
[info]   true
[info] false
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? It does not compile because the `T` in `x: C[T]` is different from the `T` in `z: Iterable[T]`. If you specify the `C[A] <: Iterable[A]` type explicitly it will compile. Can't help more without knowing what you're after

Comment: @pedromss yes that was it, thanks! :)

Comment: @pedromss but why `T` in `x: C[T]` is different from the `T` in `z: Iterable[T]` ?

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko it's not the `T` that is different, it's just that `C[_] <: Iterable[_]` specifies that `C` for *some* type is a subtype of `Iterable` for *some other* type. It doesn't need to be the case that "some type" and "some other type" are `T`. That's why we have to explicitly state that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not compile because the `T` in `x: C[T]` is different from the `T` in `z: Iterable[T]`. If you specify the `C[A] <: Iterable[A]` type explicitly it will compile.

The `T` is different because in the function signature you're using [higher kinded types](https://typelevel.org/blog/2016/08/21/hkts-moving-forward.html) which loosely state: *C is a type constructor for any type*.

Upper and Lower bounds on types are different from higher kinded types.

PS: Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, higher kinded types might not be necessary and merely be adding complexity.